# Article of Abbreviations

Tags: gender, article, standard-german

(native german speaker here). 
So I got into a little Argument about the correct article when using abbreviations.

So lets say I play in a gaming-clan called "Infanterie Regiment 42", so its "Das Infanterie Regiment 42". However, the short version of our clan is "IR42".

Is it "Das IR42", because it's "Das Infanterie Regiment 42", or is it "Die IR42" because in an abreviation the number becomes the noun and "die 42" dominates?

Comment: Why would the number become the noun?

Comment: Wenn du deutscher Muttersprachler bist, und in einem Forum, das die deutsche Sprache behandelt, eine Frage zu einem Aspekt der deutschen Sprache stellst, warum stellst du diese Frage dann in einer Fremdsprache? Mehr als 95% aller Antworten hier stammen von Menschen, deren Muttersprache ebenfalls Deutsch ist. Es gibt hier die Faustregel, dass Antworten wenn möglich in derselben Sprache zu formulieren sind, in der die Frage gestellt wurde. Dasselbe gilt für Kommentare. ...

Comment: ... Wenn du deine Frage auf Englisch stellst, führt das dann zu der perversen Situation, dass sich Leute, die schlecht Englisch aber gut Deutsch können, auf Englisch über ihre deutsche Muttersprache unterhalten.

Comment: @infinitezero: Weil Nummern Namen sind. Nummern sind Namen, die nach einem bestimmten Schema vergeben werden. »Das Infanterieregiment 42«, »die Stadt Köln«, »Der Anwalt Steingruber« und »das Schwert Nagelring« sind Begriffe, die alle nach demselben Schema funktionieren: Artikel, Klassenbezeichnung, Name des Klassenelements. Dabei kann das grammatische Geschlecht des Elements natürlich von dem der Klasse abweichen. »Das schöne Köln« ist sächlich (Städte haben einen Artikel wenn sie mit einem Attribut verwendet werden), »Die Stadt Köln« ist hingegen weiblich.

Comment: I guess *gender* would be clearer than *article* since the article depends on it, I'll add the tag at least.

Comment: To anyone complaining that I am asking a question about the german language in english. I am just used to asking questions on stackexchange and co. in english. Fells weird to do otherwise. 

Ich kann aber auch gerne deutsch sprechen, wenn es euch damit besser geht.

Comment: @guidot why gender? I thought gender was a human attribute. Not related to a certain languages grammatic. I don't think that someone interested in gender will care for the grammatic of an abbreviation. Is that tag really helpfull?

Comment: @herrendstiller No, gender is the grammatical property, which may have the values masculine, feminine or neuter. In your question the choice depends on the gender only (singular being known).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Deutsch**

Der Artikel einer Abkürzung richtet sich immer nach dem Grundwort, dass idR am Ende des Kompositas steht. Hier also "***Das*** Regiment". Die 42 ist nicht Teil der Abkürzung, daher

> Das IR 42

bzw nach eurer Schreibweise

> Das IR42

---

**English** (more detailed)

The gender of German compound words depends on the last part of the new word. So while its

> Die Infanterie
>
> Das Regiment

the compound word's article depends on Regiment, so it's as you said

> Das Infanterieregiment / Infanterie-Regiment

This is the same for abbreviations and akronyms. The gender depends on the last word. e.g. it's *Das BGB (Bürgerliche Gesetzbuch)*, because of *Das Buch*; Die AGB (Allgemeine Geschäftsbedingungen) because of Die Bedingungen; *Das JaBoG (Jagdbombergeschwader)*, because of *Das Geschwader*

Looking at Infanterie Regiment 42 the 42 is not part of the abbreviation/akronym, therefore it's

> Das IR 42

or as you write it

> Das IR42

And last but not least: Take a look at [this article about the Infanterie-Regiment 19](https://weimar.bundesarchiv.de/WEIMAR/DE/Content/Virtuelle-Ausstellungen/das-infanterie-regiment-19-in-der-zwischenkriegszeit.html) abbreviated as (das) IR 19.